# what is wrong with my method for avg?

Tags: java, methods

Yes, I know there are a lot of methods here. It's part of the assignment. In this code everything works as intended except that when numbers are entered that equal sum<=100, the "average" output is wrong. For example: if I put in 8,10,19 and zero to exit the output is count 3 sum 37 average 9.25.... the average should be 12.3333. Now, if i enter in 8, 10, 99 the output is count 3 sum 117 and average 39 which is correct. Why is it working for sum>100 but not sum<=100??? I don't get it. What am I missing?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Use Main Method for gathering input
    float input = 1;
    // Declare variable for sum
    float theSum = 0;
    // Declare variable for average
    float average = 0;
    // Declare variable for counting the number of user inputs
    int counter = 0;
    /* Initialize the while loop using an input of 0 as a sentinel value
     * to exit the loop*/
    while (input != 0) {
        if (input!=0){
            counter++;
        }
        input = Float.parseFloat(
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                null, "Please enter a number.  Enter 0 to quit: "));
        // Invoke sum method and pass input and summation to sum method


        theSum = (sum(input, theSum));
        if (theSum > 100)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The sum of your numbers "
                    + "are greater than 100!");
            break;
        }
    }
        // Invoke display method and pass summation, average, and counter variables to it
                average = (avg(theSum, counter));    
                display(theSum, average, counter);
    }


public static float sum(float num1, float sum) {
    //Add the user's input number to the sum variable
    sum += num1;
    //Return value of sum variable as new summation variable
    return sum;
}

public static float avg(float num1, float num2) {
    //Declare and initialize variable for average
    //Calculate average
    float average = num1 / num2;
    //Return value of average variable
    return average;
}

public static void display(float sum, float average, int counter) {

    /* I am subtracting 1 from variable counter so as not to include the sentinel value
     * of 0 that the user had to enter to exit the input loop in the overall count*/

    // Display the count, sum, and average to the user
    if (sum > 100) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Count = " + (counter) + ", Sum = " + sum + ", Average = " + average);
    }
    if (sum <= 100) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Count = " + (counter - 1) + ", Sum = " + sum + ", Average = " + average);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Why are you using separate methods for basic arithmetic operators?

Comment: Yep. Usually an average method will take an array or ArrayList of numbers and then calculate the average from them.

Comment: It was a requirement of the assignment. We learned methods this week, can you tell? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of the way you exit the while loop as mentioned by @chrylis. So in case where the sum is `<= 100` the counter is 1 larger. But when you print it you get correct result because you update the counter value here:

```
if (sum <= 100) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Count = " + (counter - 1) + ", Sum = " + sum + ", Average = " + average);
    }
```

As you see in your example:
"if I put in 8,10,19 and zero to exit the output is `count 3 sum 37 average 9.25`"

it is because the counter value is `4` (so the avg will be `37/4 = 9.25`), but while displaying the result you subtract counter by 1, therefore you get the count as `3`.

The do-while loop will solve the issue as the condition would be checked at the last thus the loop will exit in same manner for both `<=100` and '>100`.

The [`do-while`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop would be like this:

```
do{

//here goes your code

}while (input != 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that you're exiting the `while` loop in different ways depending on the total sum. If the sum is less than 100, even when you enter the number `0` to "exit", you're still going through the loop an extra time. To be honest, the entire loop needs to be completely restructured; a `do...while` loop would be much easier to read and debug.

Comment: Great :( I was hoping for an easy fix. How would the do...while look?

Comment: That was already answered in another of your numerous reposts. If you don't read the answers why post the questions?

Comment: Well, I obviously needed more guidance. I'm learning this on my own with 0 input from the instructor. Thanks for helping. I really am trying to "get" this. I read all the replies and try to use them. Happily, I have JUST figured it out. I created separate methods for the average and display for the statements if sum>100 and if sum<=100. I get that for you seasoned pros this is method overkill BUT as I stated in all my "numerous reposts", it was an assignment requirement. Again, thanks for your help EJP. Puzzling through your "answers" helped me figure how to solve this on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Your counter is 1 larger than necessary. Dividing by `(counter - 1)` would fix it.

Comment: right, but why does it work for sum>100? would the issue present in both cases? sum>100 and sum<=100 ??

Comment: No, it is not the same, and in fact you realized this in your `display` method, as you modify the counter in one case, but not the other.  Try re-examining what your while loop does, as @chrylis suggested